# Angular ng-repeat date formatting

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using angular ng-repeat to display an array of data including some columns which are dates but what is the best way to format the dates so they are presentable to the user? Thank you in advance.

DATES LOOK LIKE THIS IN VIEW
2016-01-14T08:00:00.000Z

WANT THIS FORMAT
January 14, 2016

```
<td width="65%" class="joinedDate">{{user.created_at}}</td>
```

Comment: did you try javascript dateformatting ? See this link https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Comment: A simple search for `angular date` would have taken you to the date filter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you format like your date (January 14, 2016) you can use

```
<td width="65%" class="joinedDate">{{user.created_at | date:'MMMM dd, yyyy'  }}</td>
```

OR

using `date : 'medium'`  default date time like `Oct 29, 2010 9:10:23 AM`

```
<td width="65%" class="joinedDate">{{user.created_at |date:'medium'}}</td>
```

for more know https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Comment: medium format displays time as well, but he don't want that.

Comment: I Wrote both code as well, and also give link where he format according himself

Answer (score 1):

You can use date **[`filter`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)**

Try like this

```
<td width="65%" class="joinedDate">{{user.created_at | date:'MMM dd, yyyy'  }}</td>
```

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/c1d0dtcs/4/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Below are some samples:

```
 <span ng-non-bindable>{{1288323623006 | date:'medium'}}</span>:
 <span>{{1288323623006 | date:'medium'}}</span><br>
 <span ng-non-bindable>{{1288323623006 | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z'}}</span>:
 <span>{{1288323623006 | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z'}}</span><br>
 <span ng-non-bindable>{{1288323623006 | date:'MM/dd/yyyy @ h:mma'}}</span>:
 <span>{{'1288323623006' | date:'MM/dd/yyyy @ h:mma'}}</span><br>
 <span ng-non-bindable>{{1288323623006 | date:"MM/dd/yyyy 'at' h:mma"}}</span>:
 <span>{{'1288323623006' | date:"MM/dd/yyyy 'at' h:mma"}}</span>
```

See [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) for more.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

[here is more about date filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

```
<td width="65%" class="joinedDate">{{ user.created_at | date:'MMMM dd, yyyy'}}</td>
```