# How to format date without using ng-bind in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to display date in `dd-mm-yyyy` format my `angualarjs` code is :

```
var tabledata = [];
tabledata.push('<td class="myclass">' + value[1][0] + '</td>')
```

I tried using below code :

```
tabledata.push('<td class="myclass" ng-bind="date:'+'"dd-mm-yyyy"'+">+value[1][0]"+"</td>")
```

This is not working. Showing the below in html:

```
<td class="myclass" ng-bind="date:" dd-mm-yyyy"="">+value[1][0]</td>)
```

Is there any alternative to achieve this?.

Comment: Try giving the date in an expression {{ }}. Check a similar post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34805167/angular-ng-repeat-date-formatting?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Regardless of how ugly, you'd need something like `tabledata.push('<td class="myclass" ng-bind="\'date:dd-mm-yyyy\'">' + value[1][0] + '</td>')` As you can see from the code highlighting in your question, you're adding the literal string `value[1][0]`, not the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the [`date pipe`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) is what you need. Check the below example for reference.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyController', function MyController($scope) {
 $scope.date = new Date();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller='MyController' ng-app="myApp">
    {{date | date: 'dd-mm-yyyy'}}
</div>
```

Comment: after adding $filter in the controller above code worked.

Comment: @jaiBalaji For pipes you do not need to add $filter in the controller, maybe you are using $filter somewhere in your controller code!